# How to set the positions of dynamicaly loaded elements using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, dynamic, position

I am working on an application that loads in "Apps" from a file on the server. At the moment i have to load the apps in a specific order otherwise they will have the wrong positions in the array of positions.

Here is the code to help explain what i mean.

```
function getFacebook() {
    var appname = "facebooka1thd";
    $.get("apps/"+appname+"/"+appname+".html", function(data){
        $('.AppList').append(data);
        $.cookie(appname, 1, { expires : 365 });
        checkpositions();
    });
};

function checkpositions() {
    if ($.cookie('PosApps')){
        var Poscookie = $.cookie('PosApps');
        var Pos = JSON.parse(Poscookie);

        $("#User").css({top:Pos[0].top, left:Pos[0].left});
        $("#facebooka1thd").css({top:Pos[1].top, left:Pos[1].left});
        $("#youtubea2thd").css({top:Pos[2].top, left:Pos[2].left});
    };
};

function getAppPositions() {
    var apps = $(".App"),
    positions = [];

    $.each(apps, function (index, app) {
        var positionInfo = $(app).position();

        positions.push(positionInfo);
        console.log(positionInfo);
    });
    var setPositions = JSON.stringify(positions);

    $.cookie("PosApps", setPositions, { expires : 365 });
};
```

I would like the code to adapt to the number off apps present and the order in which they are added or removed.

basically i dont have a clue how to get around this -_- I think that most of my code would have to change in-order for this to be possible because at the moment the positions are saved in the order in which the apps are added but that wont help when the user removes one of the apps and also the positions are being set relative to the order of the apps being added.

Any help with this would be great!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to work it out for my self...

```
function checkpositions() {
    if ($.cookie('PosApps')){
        var Poscookie = $.cookie('PosApps');
        var Pos = JSON.parse(Poscookie);

        for (var i = 0; i < Pos.length; i++) {
            $("#"+Pos[i][0]).css({top:Pos[i][1].top, left:Pos[i][1].left});
        };
    };
};

function getAppPositions() {
    var apps = $(".App"),
    positions = [];

    $.each(apps, function (index, app) {
        var id = $(app).attr('id');
        var positionInfo = [id,$(app).position()];

        positions.push(positionInfo);
        console.log(positionInfo);
    });
    var setPositions = JSON.stringify(positions);

    $.cookie("PosApps", setPositions, { expires : 365 });
};
```

All i had to do was make a 2D array with the id of the element before its position and set the CSS using Pos[i][0] for the id and Pos[i](http://www.codecademy.com/).top/left for the positions. Hope this helps anyone who gets stuck with something like this. Also if you do get stuck with a problem i would recommend going to this [site](http://www.codecademy.com/). Their tutorials are really good and are what helped me figure this problem out.